# how to secure webform by anonymous users using login form in asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net

I have a asp.net web application with three webforms say SecuredWebForm.aspx,UnSecuredWebForm.aspx and LoginForm.aspx.
i want SecuredWebForm.aspx to be accessed only when user log in using LoginForm.aspx.
and for UnSecuredWebForm.aspx,there is no need to log in.
How do i achieve it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a guide for it: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13872/Form-authentication-and-authorization-in-ASP-NET

Another guide how to do it:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301240/EN-US

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316871

Answer (score 0):

You can use this - based on `location attribute`

```
<configuration>
   <location path="SecuredWebForm.aspx">
      <system.web>
         <authorization>
            <allow users="..."/>
         </authorization>
      </system.web>
   </location>
</configuration>
```

Nota : you adjust value of users

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

If you have security architecture , you can use `IsAuthenticated` property

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.isauthenticated.aspx

```
 if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to use Membership class for this purpose. If you don`t have specific requirement.

If you have created the NewProject with WebApplication, then VisualStudio might have setup the all concern configuration for you in `web.config` something like following:

Edit `web.config` by adding `<authorization...>...</authorization>` elements. It will prevent anonymous user by accessing authorize contents.

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="ConnectionStringData" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

    <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
     </authorization>

    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    ...
    ...
  </system.web>
  ...
  ...
</configuration>
```

---

You may also need to secure the webform from anonymous users, then you may write following:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
      Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");

    // Todo add code here.        
}
```